# Java find difference between characters in StringBuffer

Tags: java, string, if-statement, for-loop, anagram

I'm working on an *Anagram* program and I'm currently working on a method called `diff` which should return a StringBuffer containing the chars that are in the first `StringBuffer` but not in the second one. So for example if the StringBuffers are `abba` and `acca`, then my diff method should return bb. So far I currently have loop with an if statement but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
public StringBuffer diff(){
    StringBuffer diffVal = null;

    for (int i =0; i < sBuffer1.length(); i++){
        String let1 = String.valueOf(sBuffer1);
        if (sBuffer2.indexOf(let1) == -1 ){

        }

    }
    return diffVal;
```

Comment: You are comparing whole buffer converted to String. So better you use index in the loop. check for each character, not for whole buffer

Comment: Why isn't `StringBuffer` dead and buried in schools?

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a loop to examine one character by one character in `sBuffer1`. But `String let1 = String.valueOf(sBuffer1);` gives you the entire string of `sBuffer1`.

What you need is `String let1 = sBuffer1.substring(i, i + 1)` to take a single character from `sBuffer1` to check if it exists in `sBuffer2`.

For example:

```
public static StringBuffer diff(StringBuffer sBuffer1, StringBuffer sBuffer2) {
    StringBuffer diffVal = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < sBuffer1.length(); i++) {
        String let1 = sBuffer1.substring(i, i + 1); // get the character from sBuffer1
        if (sBuffer2.indexOf(let1) == -1) {
            diffVal.append(let1); // append the character to the diff
        }
    }

    return diffVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this might work, your logic was a little bit wrong, this code is straight forward. search for the character if it doesn't exist in the second string buffer add it to the result SF.

```
public StringBuffer diff(){
        StringBuffer diffVal = new StringBuffer();//initialize before you use it.

        for (int i =0; i < sBuffer1.length(); i++){
            String let1 = String.valueOf(sBuffer1.charAt(i))//get the character at the ith position.
            if (sBuffer2.indexOf(let1) == -1 ){
              diffVal.append(let1);
            }

        }
        return diffVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   StringBuilder diffVal= new StringBuilder();

            StringBuffer sBuffer1 = new StringBuffer("abbad");//input 1
            StringBuffer sBuffer2 = new StringBuffer("acca");//input 2, you can ignore if you have already passed/defined these
            for (int i =0; i < sBuffer1.length(); i++){             
               if(i >= sBuffer2.length()){//handles difference in input string length
                   diffVal.append(sBuffer1.substring(i, sBuffer1.length()));
                   break;
               }
            if (sBuffer1.charAt(i) != sBuffer2.charAt(i)) {
                diffVal.append(sBuffer1.charAt(i));
            }

            }
           System.out.println(diffVal);// I am printing it here
```

the out put is : `bbd`

One recommendation here is use `StringBuilder` if you the strings you are using here are not required to be `synchronized`